# L2TP IPsec VPN client on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, vpn

I need to connect to a L2TP IPsec VPN using Ubuntu 14.10. I previously used L2TP IPsec VPN Manager 1.0.9 from Werner Jaeger in Ubuntu 14.04, and it worked great, but that no longer appears to be supported in 14.10.  I have xl2tpd installed.  I no longer see the option to add a L2TP Ipsec VPN connection under the VPN Connections menu in Network Connections.  Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I went ahead and re-installed Ubuntu 14.04 after researching and trying for several days without success.  I think I'll stick to the LTS versions for now.

Comment: This worked for me (16.04): http://blog.z-proj.com/enabling-l2tp-over-ipsec-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 19):

The lt2p-ipsec-vpn package was deprecated along with OpenSwan. Ubuntu has replaced OpenSwan with [StrongSwan](https://www.strongswan.org/), which is available in the `main`, along with a corresponding network manager plugin in `universe`.

```
apt-get install strongswan network-manager-strongswan
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It complains of missing dependency network-manager-l2pt, which I tried to install, but that depends on "openswan" which has been deprecated and removed. So I don't know what to do next.

Comment: l2tp-ipsec-vpn was deleted due to its dependency on openswan as well

Comment: Ah, so there's no way for me to do L2TP IPsec anymore?

Comment: Updated the solution, it seems to work, but I have not fully tested. No real danger from having the old repositories available since the current release takes precedence.

Comment: In the previous post of yours, you had a section about stopping a daemon and starting another one. Do I still need to do that? Btw, I did get it installed and I got it to try to connect to my L2TP server once, but then that was it. Still working away at this.

Comment: Those instructions were only relevant for the alternative network manager, you likely need to back out that change by running `sudo update-rc.d xl2tpd enable`

Comment: So after more digging, it turns out OpenSwan was completely retired and replaced with StrongSwan. (apt-get install strongswan network-manager-strongswan). So now I've installed that and it integrates nicely with the Network Manager applet. Still working on getting my pre-shared keys installed, though. If you change your answer to say that the user should install StrongSwan instead (with instructions), I'll grant you the bounty.  :)

Comment: Glad I could get you pointed somewhere near the direction :D

Comment: @Pretzel did you ever succeed in getting IPSec/L2TP to work with pre-shared keys?

Comment: Could any of you show us how it's integrated with the network manager applet. I have installed these programs but don't see any additional options in nm.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but this solution does not make L2TP available in VPN connections.

Comment: Yes, currently it doesn't show up on the network manager. This is already known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-strongswan/+bug/1578193
Fortunately, someone has applied some patches to solve this and made them available through this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~raharper/+archive/ubuntu/bugfixes

Comment: This does add "IPsec/IKEv2" to my network manager, but not L2TP. (16.04)

Answer (score 0):

StrongSwan should work with [xl2tpd](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xl2tpd)

I know it's a best practice to paste the actual scripts but it's quite a bit.  And honestly a link here would have saved me some trouble so hopefully someone finds this useful...

http://www.jasonernst.com/2016/06/21/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-on-ubuntu-16-04/
https://www.rapidvpn.com/setup-vpn-l2tp-ubuntu
https://gist.github.com/psanford/42c550a1a6ad3cb70b13e4aaa94ddb1c

Maybe after I'm done I'll share the final script.

**EDIT**

A few implementation notes

1. I had to remove the `lock` keyword from /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client
2. Username and password should be specified when `echo` into /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
3. `rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0` was added to the connection in /etc/ipsec.conf even though mine was a site-to-site VPN
4. `ip link` lists your devices.  There should be a `pppN` in the list where *N* is a number from `0`
5. For site-to-site I used the following to add a new route... `ip route add 192.168.192.0/24 dev ppp0`