# How to connect to L2TP over IPSec VPN?

Tags: vpn

I'm having trouble connecting to my company's VPN on Ubuntu 15.04.  It uses L2TP over IPsec, and I have a username, password and shared secret.  How do I connect?

Comment: Seems there is no easy way anymore to establish a L2tp VPN connection since OpenSwan has been deprecated and removed in Ubuntu 14.10. Need it myself, found no working solution after months of sporadic research.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/578881

Answer seems to be strongswan.

Comment: @Powel Szubert, can't understant the last step.
I don't know witch IP i have to use for create this route.
could you help me? please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first comment is probably the answer for most of us, except, maybe, some real experts:

"Seems there is no easy way anymore to establish a L2tp VPN connection since OpenSwan has been deprecated and removed in Ubuntu 14.10. Need it myself, found no working solution after months of sporadic research. –  derFunk May 21 at 18:11"

No solution seems to be planned, see https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/254.  Another needed functionality removed from Ubuntu.

Comment: I have proposed a solution below that should be very easy for a novice user. It doesn't involve patching the package. There are ways to do it but it's not as trivial as using the built-in functionality.

Answer (score 12):

**Update:**
A PPA exists now for `network-manager-l2tp`:

You can use

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp
```

To install the network manager l2tp that supports L2TP for Ubuntu 16.04

Walkthrough for building from source: http://blog.z-proj.com/enabling-l2tp-over-ipsec-on-ubuntu-16-04/

---

**Old Answer**

Another solution is to use network-manager-l2tp. You can get it from 
https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp.

For installation walk-through:
http://blog.z-proj.com/enabling-l2tp-over-ipsec-on-ubuntu-16-04/

It works for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I have just tested that with Ubuntu 16.04 and I can confirm that it works

Comment: Works for me too in 16.04! I had to `apt install strongswan-plugin-openssl` for "VPN service failed to start" in Network Manager which was caused by `ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM 3DES_CBC (key size 0) not supported!` in syslog.

Comment: There's now a PPA, which simplifies the installation.   One note: I did have to stop the system xl2tpd service with `sudo service xl2tpd stop` before I could connect to my VPN -- otherwise xl2tpd would ignore the IPsec tunnel and try connecting directly over L2TP.

Comment: You will also need a GUI: `apt install network-manager-l2tp-gnome`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/934350/connect-to-l2tp-over-ipsec

Comment: This also worked for me on 16.04 LTS, and as @JulienCarsique mentioned, also had to run `apt install network-manager-l2tp-gnome` along with `network-manager-l2tp` (this should be the accepted answer IMO)

Answer (score 3):

Patch NM-L2TP package with script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
CUR_PATH=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
TMP_PATH=/tmp/nm-l2tp
mkdir ${TMP_PATH}
cd ${TMP_PATH}
wget https://launchpad.net/~seriy-pr/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp/+build/6512073/+files/network-manager-l2tp_0.9.8.5-0utopic1_amd64.deb
ar vx network-manager-l2tp_0.9.8.5-0utopic1_amd64.deb
mkdir new
tar -xpvf data.tar.xz -C ./new
mv ./new/usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5 ./new/usr/lib/pppd/2.4.6
sed -i 's/2.4.5/2.4.6/g' ./new/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-l2tp-service
sed -i 's/2.4.5/2.4.6/g' ./new/usr/lib/pppd/2.4.6/nm-l2tp-pppd-plugin.so
mkdir new/DEBIAN
tar -xpvf control.tar.gz -C ./new/DEBIAN
sed -i 's/, ppp (<< 2.4.6)//g' ./new/DEBIAN/control
sed -i 's/0utopic1/0vivid1/g' ./new/DEBIAN/control
rm ./new/DEBIAN/md5sums
dpkg-deb -b ./new/ ${CUR_PATH}/network-manager-l2tp_0.9.8.5-0vivid1_amd64.deb
rm -rf ${TMP_PATH}
```

Then download and install an appropriate Openswan package from the http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/openswan and run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i network-manager-l2tp_0.9.8.5-0vivid1_amd64.deb
sudo service xl2tpd stop
sudo update-rc.d xl2tpd disable
```

Then just go to the Network manager, choose VPN connections and create l2tp. You need only set up a username, password and the IPSec PSK in the IPSec additional settings.

Part taken from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581981/vpn-l2tp-connection-on-ubuntu-14-10)

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately this doesn't seem to work (no l2tp option in Network Manager).

Comment: Tested on two PCs with Kubuntu 15.04 and it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround, tested on 15.10, should work on 15.04 also.
Requires manual editing of conffiles and manual establishing connection.

- leave original strongswan from ubuntu repo
- remove xl2tpd package (U can try with xl2tpd but on my computer xl2tpd crashed with segfault on every start)
- install openl2tpd from:
  ftp://ftp.openl2tp.org/releases/openl2tp-1.8/debian-squeeze/openl2tp_1.8-1_amd64.deb
- edit /etc/ipsec.conf:

`config setup
        strictcrlpolicy=yes
 conn %default
        ikelifetime=30m
        keylife=15m
        rekeymargin=3m
        keyingtries=1
        mobike=no
        dpdaction=restart
        dpddelay=30
        dpdtimeout=120
 conn MYSERVER
        left=192.168.101.157
        leftprotoport=17/1701
        right=77.78.79.80            # public IP of VPN gw
        rightprotoport=17/1701
        authby=secret
        type=transport
        keyexchange=ikev1
        auto=route`

- edit /etc/ipsec.secrets:

`: PSK "StrongPSKgivenByProvider"`

- edit (or create) /etc/openl2tpd.conf:

`ppp profile modify profile_name=default \
        auth_eap=no auth_mschapv1=no auth_mschapv2=no
tunnel create tunnel_name=MYSERVER \
        dest_ipaddr=77.78.79.80 \
        hello_timeout=10 \
        retry_timeout=10 \
        max_retries=60 \
        persist=yes
session create session_name=MeOnMYSERVER \
        tunnel_name=MYSERVER \
        interface_name=ppp1 \
        user_name=MyLogin \
        user_password=MyPassword`

- restart and test ipsec:

  `ipsec restart
  ipsec status`
- output should be like this:

  `Routed Connections:
    MYSERVER{1}:  ROUTED, TRANSPORT
    MYSERVER{1}:   192.168.101.157/32[udp/l2f] === 77.78.79.80/32[udp/l2f] 
  Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):
  none`
- connect

  `sudo service openl2tpd restart
  sudo route add -net {net_behing_VPN_gateway/mask} gw {local_IP_of_VPN_gw}`

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: what is the "{net_behing_VPN_gateway/mask}" in the last command? can you write an example with the actual numbers please?

Answer (score 2):

Note that for the accepted answer, the correct installation command for Ubuntu 18 is

```
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp network-manager-l2tp-gnome
```

Since Ubuntu now ships with Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to get l2tp-ipsec on 15.04 but its not very elegant.

I uninstalled strongswan and installed an old openswan trusty .deb package.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/openswan

I then found .deb files of the old l2tp-ipsec-vpn and l2tp-ipsec-vpn-daemon from trusty by Werner Jaeger.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/l2tp-ipsec-vpn

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-daemon

I installed those, and after I restarted, I was able to connect. However, this took quite a bit of time to get working properly and required installing deprecated packages.

I think that's all I did but if you try this and get another error there may be another package I installed I don't remember.

**UPDATE**: I had to do this again so I figured I would share the steps.
Install the old client: https://launchpad.net/l2tp-ipsec-vpn

Again this is a workaround if you need it in pinch and currently works. That being said, this really needs to be apart of the OS.

```
sudo apt-get install gksu libgksu2-0 libctemplate2 libengine-pkcs11-openssl libp11-2 xl2tpd
```

Next download the old binaries and install with dpkg:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openswan/openswan_2.6.38-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i openswan_2.6.38-1_amd64.deb 

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/l2tp-ipsec-vpn/l2tp-ipsec-vpn_1.0.9-1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-daemon/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-daemon_0.9.9-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i l2tp-ipsec-vpn_1.0.9-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i l2tp-ipsec-vpn-daemon_0.9.9-1_amd64.deb
```

Open the client. Add a connection and configure as needed. Once you try to connect it may take awhile but be patient.

Comment: I tried many solutions for my ubuntu 16.04, only this one works! Thank you a lot!

Comment: I know this is not related, but for anyone interested: it doesn't work on debian 9.0 (the GUI doesn't render properly).

Comment: For Debian 9.0, use network-manager-l2tp and network-manager-l2tp-gnome packages from Debian Sid:
https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/network-manager-l2tp