# L2TP IPsec VPN client on Ubuntu Desktop 16.04

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I try to setup a vpn client on my ubuntu desktop. I know that some packet are now deprecated and not supported in 16.04. I've tried to run `sudo apt-get install strongswan network-manager-strongswan` like suggested this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569763/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-14-10/578881) but it doesn't seems to change anything. I only get the PPTP protocol under "new VPN connection"

I manage to get the VPN working for windows, macos and even ios but since the recent release of ubuntu and debian it looks like a real nightmare to configure L2TP/IPsec on those platform

Comment: We don't know how accurately you followed the linked procedure, nor what the results of each command were on YOUR system. How are we supposed to help?

Comment: @waltinator it's literally one command line so appart from making a typo how could you possibly get the "procedure" wrong ? regarding the output there isn't much to say if there is no error is it ? ( I would have started by that it was the case... ) The issue must comes from that not be enough to setup the vpn...

Comment: Same problem here. I think, like me. The OP expects that by installing the network-manager-strongswan package, that we would be able to go > Network Manager > Connect to VPN > Add > IPSEC VPN Connection. Except that install network-manager-strongswan seems to do nothing for the menu options.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/617785/how-to-connect-to-l2tp-over-ipsec-vpn, as 16.x does not have out-of-the-box support for L2TP.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-strongswan/+bug/1578193) about this.
Error message when starting network manager from Terminal:

```
$ nm-connection-editor 
** Message: vpn: (strongswan,/etc/NetworkManager/VPN/nm-strongswan-service.name) cannot load legacy-only plugin
```