# L2TP/IPsec NetworkManager plugin using only username, password and PSK

Tags: network-manager, vpn, ipsec

I've Googled around and found three GUI methods to configure L2TP/IPsec VPN (the last of which is not a NM plugin, but a standalone program):

- [`network-manager-l2tp`](https://launchpad.net/~seriy-pr/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp)

I'd have preferred to use this even if it's been declared unmaintaned on it's GitHub page, but the only way to use specify the PSK is by specifying some group. Nothing of that sort was configured on the VPN server.

- [`network-manager-strongswan`](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/NetworkManager)

No PSK option at all, insists on certificates as noted by [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586751/where-to-add-the-pre-shared-key-for-the-server-authentication-with-network-manag) as well.

- [`l2tp-ipsec-vpn`](https://launchpad.net/l2tp-ipsec-vpn)

It allowed me to specify the only three things I need to connect to my VPN, but it always fails due to some mysterious `Error 500`. The only way to look at the connection log is my clicking the notification. But of course, we can't do that on Ubuntu.

The VPN service is served by SoftEther VPN. I've enabled L2TP/IPsec protocols on it, and my friend successfully connected to it using his iPhone, Macbook and a Windows 10 machine with just those three things: username, password and the pre-shared key. How do I do the same on Ubuntu?

Comment: in network-manager-l2tp the group is the leftid in the secrets file, if left blank it defaults to %any. Networ-manager-strongswan has no l2tp support whatsoever.

Comment: If I use `%any` as Group Name on the `network-manager-l2tp` itself, can I expect it to connect?

Comment: try leaving both gateway id and group name blank.

Comment: @adonis It automatically defaults to whatever it's written there if I leave it empty.