# how can create l2tp vpn conncection and disable IPSec in 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, vpn, ipsec

My company give me just username and pasword with the server address for L2TP vpn connection and say to disable IPSec for connecting,
They are have Win and Mac Tutorial for using the VPN but don't have any help to create connection in ubuntu?
how can create the L2TP vpn and disable IPSec? and use just username and password with server address?

I have installed the StrongSwan with this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569763/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-14-10/578881#578881) ...