# How to configure IPSec VPN on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, network-manager, vpn, ipsec

In order to connect to the VPN I only need a few configuration options:

`server.domain.name`
`PSK`
`user`
`pass`

What is the proper way to configure an IPSec VPN connection on my Ubuntu 15.04?

I installed `strongswan` but I don't know how to configure `/etc/ipsec.conf` and `/etc/ipsec.secrets`. Their official documentation is a little confusing for the few options I need.

I also installed `network-manager` plug-ins like: `OpenVPN` and `strongswan`, **but their interface requires certificate files to be entered and I cannot type the PSK**.

network-manager-strongswan IPSec/IKEv2 example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlfyc.jpg

Also I know this post may be realated to [L2TP IPsec VPN client on Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569763/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-14-10)
, but I didn't find an answer there.

Comment: Going through this pain over a year later...