# IPSEC/L2TP Ubuntu Studio 14.04 (Strongswan)

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, vpn

My first question: Does Ubuntu support IPSEC/L2TP/PSK vpn CLIENT?

My Second Question: Is there a front end "Network Manager" that supports IPSEC/L2TP and PSK?

> Background:

In my endeavors I came across this article: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/264691 - which i have attempted to use the suggestions in - but am still not able to get a working IPSEC/L2TP/PSK tunnel up as it refrences using openswan.

> The Situation:

I was using Werner Jaeger ipsec client and it worked flawlessly - about 3 or 4 months ago it has stopped working. I have attempted to reinstall it on my desktop using Ubuntu Studio 14.04 and Debian 8 and I get the same results.

I now understand that openswan was removed from the distro and superseded by strongswan. I very much would not like to have to move away from linux as one of the things i do is work from home and need vpn to monitor / test / configure networks. Can someone point me to a good tutorial on configuring it as a client?

> Side note:

I found this topic [L2TP IPsec VPN client on Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569763/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-14-10) - tried all the things in there - still nothing - also that article did not answer the question being that it is for 14.10 and im using 14.04 it is technically different - I have done alot of things thus far to get it to work and nothing has helped. Any help would be much appreciated!!!

---

Sorry to dump like this here - seriously - i am desperate to get this working and am at my ends with it - it has been like 3 months now since i was able to work on my desktop. All of the research I have done leads me to believe that open swan will not work anymore and I have to use strongswan. (am i wrong?)

so some things i have been trying to do -

Using strongswan I tried doing this:

```
apt-get install strongswan network-manager-strongswan
```

It is my understanding that I should see a L2TP/IPSEC option in the network manager. (am i wrong?)

The problem is that l2tp/ipsec/psk as not an option in the network manager after all was installed and rebooted

Also the Werner Jaeger applet disappears after going to strongswan, is that expected?

Next thing I tried to do -

I rolled my machine back to openswan and for the first time in months it gets connected - though after a couple seconds it drops - I figured I'd run 'ipsec verify' to check statuses - below is my steps and my logs minus the sensitive details - any thoughts would be much appreciated

What I ran with to install -

```
sudo apt-get install openswan
sudo apt-get install xl2tpd
sudo apt-get install l2tp-ipsec-vpn
```

I then configured the gui applet

I then configured the file:

```
/etc/ppp/watevs.options.xl2tpd
```

-Logs-

```
jason@casa-wesella:~$ sudo ipsec verify

Checking your system to see if IPsec got installed and started correctly:

Version check and ipsec on-path                                 [OK]

Linux Openswan U2.6.38/K3.16.0-43-lowlatency (netkey)

Checking for IPsec support in kernel                            [OK]

 SAref kernel support                                           [N/A]

 NETKEY:  Testing XFRM related proc values                      [FAILED]

  Please disable /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/send_redirects
  or NETKEY will cause the sending of bogus ICMP redirects!     [FAILED]

  Please disable /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/accept_redirects
  or NETKEY will accept bogus ICMP redirects!                   [OK]

Checking that pluto is running                                  [OK]

 Pluto listening for IKE on udp 500                             [OK]

 Pluto listening for NAT-T on udp 4500                          [OK]

Two or more interfaces found, checking IP forwarding        Checking NAT and MASQUERADEing                                  [OK]

Checking for 'ip' command                                       [OK]

Checking /bin/sh is not /bin/dash                               [WARNING]

Checking for 'iptables' command                                 [OK]

Opportunistic Encryption Support                                [DISABLED]




> Logs from applet -



Jul 21 15:23:45.505 ipsec_setup: Starting Openswan IPsec U2.6.38/K3.16.0-43-lowlatency...

Jul 21 15:23:46.412 ipsec__plutorun: Starting Pluto subsystem...

Jul 21 15:23:46.659 ipsec__plutorun: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d

Jul 21 15:23:46.749 recvref[30]: Protocol not available

Jul 21 15:23:46.749 xl2tpd[2313]: This binary does not support kernel L2TP.

Jul 21 15:23:46.749 xl2tpd[2316]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.6 started on casa-wesella PID:2316

Jul 21 15:23:46.750 xl2tpd[2316]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 
1998, Adtran, Inc.

Jul 21 15:23:46.750 xl2tpd[2316]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001

Jul 21 15:23:46.750 xl2tpd[2316]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002

Jul 21 15:23:46.750 xl2tpd[2316]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006

Jul 21 15:23:46.751 xl2tpd[2316]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701

Jul 21 15:23:46.752 Starting xl2tpd: xl2tpd.

Jul 21 15:23:46.891 ipsec__plutorun: 027 bad right --id: does not look numeric and name lookup failed (ignored)

Jul 21 15:23:46.892 ipsec__plutorun: 002 added connection description "Work"

Jul 21 15:23:47.123 104 "Work" #1: STATE_MAIN_I1: initiate

Jul 21 15:23:47.124 003 "Work" #1: received Vendor ID payload [RFC 3947] method set to=115 

Jul 21 15:23:47.124 003 "Work" #1: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]

Jul 21 15:23:47.124 003 "Work" #1: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [8299031757a36082c6a621de00050282]

Jul 21 15:23:47.124 106 "Work" #1: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2

Jul 21 15:23:47.124 003 "Work" #1: NAT-Traversal: Result using draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike (MacOS X): i am NATed

Jul 21 15:23:47.124 108 "Work" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3

Jul 21 15:23:47.124 004 "Work" #1: STATE_MAIN_I4: ISAKMP SA established {auth=OAKLEY_PRESHARED_KEY cipher=oakley_3des_cbc_192 prf=oakley_sha group=modp1024}

Jul 21 15:23:47.125 117 "Work" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: initiate

Jul 21 15:23:47.125 003 "Work" #2: ignoring informational payload, type IPSEC_RESPONDER_LIFETIME msgid=8e08921c

Jul 21 15:23:47.125 003 "Work" #2: NAT-Traversal: received 2 NAT-OA. ignored because peer is not NATed

Jul 21 15:23:47.125 004 "Work" #2: STATE_QUICK_I2: sent QI2, IPsec SA established transport mode {ESP=>0x37742a26 <0x478d0d00 xfrm=AES_128-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=none DPD=none}

Jul 21 15:23:48.129 xl2tpd[2316]: Connecting to host Public IP, port 1701

Jul 21 15:23:48.168 xl2tpd[2316]: Connection established to Public IP, 1701.  Local: 57627, Remote: 14608 (ref=0/0).

Jul 21 15:23:48.194 xl2tpd[2316]: Calling on tunnel 57627

Jul 21 15:23:48.212 xl2tpd[2316]: Call established with Public IP, Local: 14783, Remote: 14609, Serial: 1 (ref=0/0)

Jul 21 15:23:48.212 xl2tpd[2316]: start_pppd: I'm running: 

Jul 21 15:23:48.213 xl2tpd[2316]: "/usr/sbin/pppd" 

Jul 21 15:23:48.213 xl2tpd[2316]: "passive" 

Jul 21 15:23:48.213 xl2tpd[2316]: "nodetach" 

Jul 21 15:23:48.214 xl2tpd[2316]: ":" 

Jul 21 15:23:48.214 xl2tpd[2316]: "file" 

Jul 21 15:23:48.214 xl2tpd[2316]: "/etc/ppp/Work.options.xl2tpd" 

Jul 21 15:23:48.215 xl2tpd[2316]: "/dev/pts/6" 

Jul 21 15:23:48.331 pppd[2427]: Plugin passprompt.so loaded.

Jul 21 15:23:48.332 pppd[2427]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0

Jul 21 15:23:48.333 pppd[2427]: Using interface ppp0

Jul 21 15:23:48.333 pppd[2427]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/6

Jul 21 15:23:52.345 pppd[2427]: Remote message: Login ok

Jul 21 15:23:52.346 pppd[2427]: PAP authentication succeeded

Jul 21 15:23:52.390 pppd[2427]: Deflate (15) compression enabled

Jul 21 15:23:52.429 pppd[2427]: local  IP address Private IP

Jul 21 15:23:52.429 pppd[2427]: remote IP address Private IP

Jul 21 15:24:31.977 Stopping xl2tpd: xl2tpd.

Jul 21 15:24:31.977 xl2tpd[2316]: death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received

Jul 21 15:24:31.979 pppd[2427]: Modem hangup

Jul 21 15:24:31.979 pppd[2427]: Connect time 0.7 minutes.

Jul 21 15:24:31.980 pppd[2427]: Sent 10334 bytes, received 13370 bytes.

Jul 21 15:24:31.980 pppd[2427]: Connection terminated.

Jul 21 15:24:31.993 ipsec_setup: Stopping Openswan IPsec...

Jul 21 15:24:32.089 pppd[2427]: Exit.
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Same issue for me

Comment: nope - unfortunately, still cant get the vpn to stay up for more than a minute or 2. Fortunately my company has migrated us onto VDI and we are able to use a thin client remotely now... so it has not been a pressing issue as of late.  Once i get some free time im going to hack away at this again and post the results here as the ipsec/l2tp is still available.